# How do I get an Express Form to upload an image to S3 and then save the S3 URL to a mongoDB field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3

I seem to be stuck here. I have a form that I use to write blog posts where I previously used multer to upload images to mongodb as a datastream. After realizing scalability issues I was going to try and get it to upload to S3, but I am having some issues.

The Post route coming from the form is as follows:

```
// REQUIREMENTS
require("dotenv").config();
const   express     =   require("express"),
        router      =   express.Router(),
        Posts       =   require("../models/blog"),
        upload      =   require("../middleware/upload"),
        path        =   require('path'),
        fs          =   require('fs'),
        middleware  =   require("../middleware"),
        slugify     =   require('slugify');

// CREATE (POST To root of this router)
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single('uploadedImage'), function(req,res){

    var title =     req.body.title;
    var image =     //where I would like the S3 link to go eventually
    var postdata =  req.body.postdata;
    var exceprt =   req.body.excerpt;
    var tag =       req.body.tag;
    var icon =      req.body.icon;
    var color =     req.body.color;
    var featured =  req.body.featured;
    var keywords    = req.body.keywords;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var dest        = req.file.filename;
    var slug        = slugify(title);
    var uploadedImage = {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join('./public/assets/img/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        };
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };
    // link dB to post values
    var newPost= {title:title, slug:slug, image:image, postdata:postdata, excerpt:exceprt, tag:tag, icon:icon, color:color, featured:featured, author:author, keywords:keywords, description:description, dest:dest, uploadedImage:uploadedImage};
    Posts.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("slug:" + slug);
            console.log(req.file.path);
            res.redirect("/blog");
        }
    });
});
```

it uses the multer middleware upload here:

```
// ORIGINAL
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './public/assets/img');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage });
```

I have seen a code block like this for getting the image to S3

```
require("dotenv").config();
const   multer      = require('multer'),
        multerS3    = require('multer-s3'),
        { S3Client }= require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');


// AWS AUTHORIZATION
let s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  sslEnabled: false,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```

I think the authorization style is right and I have a .env file with all my correct variables in it. I just can't seem to configure the route and the middleware to do what I would like. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some checks on my middleware I realized I was trying to pass in objects incorrectly. For anyone who wants to submit a form and have it uploaded to AWS S3 use this formula.

POST Route *(My variables are from my form names- please adjust them to your form names so body-parser can assign the values accordingly)*:

```
// REQUIRE STATEMENTS
const   express     =   require("express"),
        router      =   express.Router(),
        Posts       =   require("../models/blog"),
        upload      =   require("../middleware/upload"),
        middleware  =   require("../middleware"),
        slugify     =   require('slugify');

// CREATE (POST To root of this router)
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, upload.single('uploadedImage'), function(req,res){

    var title =     req.body.title;
    var image =     req.file.location;
    var postdata =  req.body.postdata;
    var exceprt =   req.body.excerpt;
    var tag =       req.body.tag;
    var icon =      req.body.icon;
    var color =     req.body.color;
    var featured =  req.body.featured;
    var keywords    = req.body.keywords;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var slug        = slugify(title);
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };

    // link dB to post values
    var newPost= {title:title, slug:slug, image:image, postdata:postdata, excerpt:exceprt, tag:tag, icon:icon, color:color, featured:featured, author:author, keywords:keywords, description:description};
    Posts.create(newPost, function(err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("slug:" + slug);
            console.log(req.file);
            res.redirect("/blog");
        }
    });
});
```

Middleware:

```
// S3 UPLOADS
require("dotenv").config();
const   multer      = require('multer'),
        multerS3    = require('multer-s3'),
        { S3Client }= require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');


// AWS AUTHORIZATION
let s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  sslEnabled: false,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    acl: 'public-read',
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```